# Rate limit exceeded - only used on one computer

Tags: plaid

I'm getting an error with Plaid that my rate limit has been exceeded, since I have 5 items in use on my developer account. I have only used Plaid on my localhost from my browser, and the quickstart app to look up my actual accounts. I'm confused how it thinks these are new systems - and also how to release one of these items so it frees up developer slots. The documentation says I can hit the release route, but that that doesn't restore an item slot.

Is there anything I'm missing?

{
"display_message": null,
"documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#rate-limit-exceeded-errors",
"error_code": "ADDITION_LIMIT",
"error_message": "addition limit exceeded for this client_id. contact support to increase the limit.",
"error_type": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
"request_id": "#####",
"suggested_action": null
}

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes you are not the first person to be confused by this! You need to request access to Development via the Plaid dashboard, which, once approved, will unlock access to 95 additional Items. You can do this here: https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview/development

The number of computers you are using doesn't matter, the only thing being counted is Items -- each Item takes up one slot, but in Development deleting Items does not free up slots.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I guess my follow-up is how do I restore items for development? I was going through the web GUI and looked up actual bank accounts, closed the tabs and  cannot get access back to the items. I'm hoping to just make a simple app for personal usage to brush up on the API and try a couple backend languages, which if I can get away with doing on a free dev account would be helpful.

Comment: If you forgot to save the access tokens anywhere, you can file a support ticket via the Dashboard. Plaid Support should be able to send you a list of your active access tokens.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Sorry for basic questions.